# Uncheck/Disable checked "Same as Billing Address" in magento 1.5

Tags: magento

Basically, I've been trying to remove the checked box when I go to the following.

Sales > Order > View a completed order > Click Re-Order   and then I see the SHIPPING ADDRESS has a checkbox which is already checked SAME AS BILLING ADDRESS. I want to uncheck the box and disable this function.

Please let me know how I can do this is the simplest way possible.

Magento Version 1.5.0.1

Comment: What do you mean disable? Shipping address always must be = billing address? Or user must type shipping address each time on order re-order?

Comment: @Zyava Hello Zyava, Basically, I am talking about completed orders in admin panel. When I go to re-order a completed order than I want to the check on the SHIPPING ADDRESS as Same as billing to be unchecked by default. Please check this link http://i52.tinypic.com/21e4y9t.png. You see the Same as billing address checked? I want it un-checked and want details to be entered manually instead of using details from Billing Address. Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 2):

I found this and it worked perfect.

http://www.12live.de/de/blog/magento/magento-create-order-in-backend-set-default-value-of-delivery-address-checkbox-same-as-billing-to-unchecked/

If you create an order in the backend by default the delivery method checkbox "Same as billing" is checked.
If the customer has different billing and shipping address this is problematic. In the dop down the shipping address is shown. But due to the checkbox the shown shipping address is ignored and the billing address wil be used for delivery. If you want the checkbox to be unchecked by default the following modification is needed. Recommended is to copy the file from the core to the local code pool and modifiy it there. The file in question is `core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/adress.php`. You need to change line 124 to:

```
$this->setSameAsBilling(0);
```